# The terminal on my Mac does not work anymore after installing Python & Sublime Text

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, python

I was trying to install Python3, and Sublime Text 3 in order to learn and run Python. Unfortunately, I watched some videos on youtube and tried to follow their instructions, I did something with my Terminal and now **it does not work at all**. Please explain and show me how to fix it!

In Terminal it shows:

```
Last login: Sun May  1 18:44:16 on ttys000
Lances-MacBook-Pro:~ lancedang$ touch
-bash: touch: command not found
Lances-MacBook-Pro:~ lancedang$ python
-bash: python: command not found
Lances-MacBook-Pro:~ lancedang$ python3
-bash: python3: command not found
```

Comment: Please add the youtube video links or at least the instructions you followed.

Comment: It is *Terminal* that doesn't work or *Python*?

Comment: The terminal does not work

Comment: I saw someone has the same problem and they add this: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin It work after I add that but just for temporary, after I quit and reopen, I have them same problem

Comment: Type `echo $PATH` and paste the results.

Comment: this is the link: https://blog.penjee.com/setting-up-python-on-mac/

Comment: This is the result after I type              echo $PATH         
/Users/lancedang/bin:

Comment: Please paste the output for this command `cat ~/.bash_profile | grep export`.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I got this: -bash: cat: command not found
-bash: grep: command not found

Comment: `/bin/cat ~/.bash_profile | /usr/bin/grep export`

Comment: @AndrewLarsson  I got this: export PATH
export PATH=~/bin:$PATHexport PATH

Comment: @AndrewLarsson sorry I was wrong , I got this: # Setting PATH for Python 3.4  # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave  |  PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"  |  export PATH    | # Setting PATH for Python 3.5  |  
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave  |  
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PATH` environment variable seems to have been changed somewhere.

Type the following command at your Terminal prompt:

`echo 'PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Exit terminal and the shell by typing `exit` and closing the Terminal app. Relaunch.

Everything should be working now.

Comment: I added `~/bin:$PATH` to it, so it will keep his Python working.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson It works, Thanks a lot!!! Also can you please show me how can I link the sublime text 3 to run python3, I am really new with python3

Comment: @LDbunny I'd suggest heading over to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext) for questions about Sublime Text. They'd be able to help you better.